# Determine actually mounted volumes and remote file systems in OSX

Tags: macos, unix, filesystems

I need to gather a list of all mounted "mount points" that the local file system has access to.

This includes:

- Any ordinarily mounted volume under `/Volumes`.
- Any NFS volume that's currently mounted under `/net`.
- Any local or remote file system mounted with the "mount" command or auto-mounted somehow.

But I need to *avoid* accessing any file systems that can be auto-mounted but are currently not mounted. I.e, I do not want to cause any auto-amounting.

My current method is as follows:

1. Call `FSGetVolumeInfo()` in a loop to gather all known volumes. This will give me all local drives under `/Volumes` as well as `/net, /home`, and NFS mounts under `/net`.
2. Call `FSGetVolumeParms()` to get each volume's "device ID" (this turns out to be the mount path for network volumes).
3. If the ID is a POSIX path (i.e. it's starting with "/"), I use `readdir()` on its path's parent to check whether the parent dir contains actually the mount point item (e.g. if ID is `/net/MyNetShare`, then I readdir `/net`). If it's not available, I assume this is a auto-mount point with a yet-unmounted volume and therefore exclude it from my list of mounted volumes.
4. Lastly, if the volume appears mounted, I check if it contains any items. If it does, I add it to my list.

Step 3 is necessary to see whether the path is actually mounted. If I'd instead call `lstat()` on the full path, it would attempt to automount the file system, which I need to avoid.

Now, even though the above works most of the time, there are still some issues:

- The mix of calls to the BSD and Carbon APIs, along with special casing the "device ID" value, is rather unclean.
- The `FSGetVolumeInfo()` call gives me mount points such as "/net" and "/home" even though these do not seem to be actual mount points - the mount points would rather appear *inside* these. For example, if I'd mount a NFS share at "/net/MyNFSVolume", I'd gather both a "/net" point and a "/net/MyNFSVolume", but the "/net" point is no actual volume.
- Worst of all, *sometimes* the above process still causes active attempts to contact the off-line server, leading to long timeouts.

So, who can show me a better way to find all the actually mounted volumes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the BSD level function `getattrlist()`, asking for the `ATTR_DIR_MOUNTSTATUS` attribute, one can test the `DIR_MNTSTATUS_TRIGGER` flag.

This flag seems to be only set when an automounted share point is currently unreachable. The status of this flag appears to be directly related to the mount status maintained by the `automountd` daemon that manages re-mounting such mount points: As long as `automountd` reports that a mount point isn't available, due to the server not responding, the "trigger" flag is set.

Note, however, that this status is not immediately set once a network share becomes inaccessible. Consider this scenario:

The file `/etc/auto_master` has this line added at the end:

```
/-                      auto_mymounts
```

The file `/etc/auto_mymounts` has the following content:

```
/mymounts/MYSERVER1      -nfs,soft,bg,intr,net    myserver1:/
```

This means that there will be a auto-mounting directory at `/mymounts/MYSERVER1`, giving access to the root of myserver1's exported NFS share.

Let's assume the server is initially reachable. Then we can browse the directory at /mymounts/MYSERVER1, and the `DIR_MNTSTATUS_TRIGGER` flag will be cleared.

Next, let's make the server become unreachable by simply killing the network connection (such as removing the ethernet cable to turning off Wi-Fi). At this point, when trying to access /mymounts/MYSERVER1 again, we'll get delays and timeouts, and we might even get seemingly valid results such as non-empty directory listings despite the unavailable server. The `DIR_MNTSTATUS_TRIGGER` flag will remain cleared at this point.

Now put the computer to sleep and wake it up again. At this point, `automountd` tries to reconnect all auto-mounted volumes again. It will notice that the server is offline and put the mount point into "trigger" state. Now the `DIR_MNTSTATUS_TRIGGER` flag will be set as desired.

So, while this trigger flag is not the perfect indicator to tell when the remote server is unreachable, it's good enough to tell when the server has become offline for a longer time, as it's usually happening when moving the client computer between different networks, such as between work and home, with the computer being put to sleep in between, thus causing the automountd daemon to detect the reachability of the NFS server.